# "using" vs. "with" vs. "in"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-meaning

I have a question about the following sentence:

> Built web scrapers using/with/in Python in order to extract data from target websites.

On the web I see that the terms *using*, *with* and *in* are used interchangeably. But are these three terms equivalent in this case?

Please note that a web scraper can be viewed as a software while Python is a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are completely interchangeable and they all mean the same thing.

> Build web scrapers using Python...
>
> Build web scrapers with Python...
>
> Build web scrapers in Python...

For operating systems or platforms, you can also use "on":

> Build web scrapers in Python on Windows...
>
> Build web scrapers using Python on Linux...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Other than that, is my sentence overall grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically correct: "Built web scrapers using/with/in Python in order to extract data from target websites."

Comment: I have another small question here: what could be the most appropriate synonym for *extract* in this case? *gather*? *collect*? *retrieve*? Anything else?

Comment: Those are all fine, but "extract" is better because it implies that you're doing more than just collecting it. You can also say "pull," but that's a little less formal. Extract is probably best.